# multiple criteria including near and textcriteri is not working in spring data mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to make a `geospital` query including `full text search`. But it is not working.
Let me share my code. My mongo instance is `2.6` which supports full text search. The query works well with geoNear and category criteria. However when I add the `textcriteri` it is not working. Moreover, I dont know how to get list of SEvent object from GeoResult.
my second question, is it possible to return more than 100 documents from geo near query? 
Because according to my requirement; for instance, user will start to search first 1km away points. and then if he wants more content, he can ask 'ok give me contents min 1km max 2km' and so on... Could not find any advanced information about my problem through whole internet. that is why asking for your help.

```
public List<SEvent> searchEventByTxt(String txt, String catId, double longitude, double latitude) throws SowException{
    Category cat = null;
    Query secondQ = null;
    if(!catId.equals("-1")){
        cat = categoryService.findById(catId);
        if (txt != null && txt.length() > 0) {
            secondQ = new Query(Criteria.where("catId").is(cat.getId()).and(TextCriteria.forLanguage(new Locale(SOW.Session.current().getLang()).getLanguage()).matching(txt).getKey()));

        } else {
            secondQ = new Query(Criteria.where("catId").is(cat.getId()));
        }
    } else {
        if (txt != null && txt.length() > 0) {
            secondQ = new TextQuery(TextCriteria.forLanguage(new Locale(SOW.Session.current().getLang()).getLanguage()).matching(txt));
        }
    }

    Point point = new Point(longitude, latitude);
    NearQuery nq = NearQuery.near(point).maxDistance(new Distance(2, Metrics.KILOMETERS));

    if(secondQ != null)
        nq.query(secondQ);

    GeoResults<SEvent> res = mo.geoNear(nq, Adv.class);
    List<GeoResult<SEvent>> list =  res.getContent();

    for (GeoResult<SEvent> geoResult : list) {
        System.out.println(geoResult.getContent().getTitle());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this documentation: [Queries cannot use both text and Geospatial Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Queries-cannot-use-both-text-and-Geospatial-Indexes)    Not every combination of indexes is supported

Comment: Thnak you for your answer. Yes you are right. Interesting! This was a very common case. very bad could not to do that. Do you have any advice? any advanced regex for text search?